# Shooting bullets to enemy that it has range

Tags: c++, sfml

Every little amout of time every tower creates a bullet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < towerVec.size(); i++)
{
    Tower_shot tshot(&bulletTexture, sf::Vector2u(1, 3), towerVec[i].row);
    tshot.tower_shot.setPosition(towerVec[i].getPosX(), towerVec[i].getPosY());
    tshot.startingX = towerVec[i].getPosX();
    tshot.startingY = towerVec[i].getPosY();
    tshotVec.push_back(tshot);
}
```

Then every bullet is shot:

```
for (int j = 0; j < enemyVec.size(); j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tshotVec.size(); i++)
    {
        if (tshotVec[i].ifFire(enemyVec[j].body.getPosition())) 
            tshotVec[i].fire(enemyVec[j].body.getPosition(), window);
    }
}
```

Shooting functions are checking if have range to reach enemy, if not, trying with another one.

```
bool Tower_shot::ifFire(sf::Vector2f EnemyPos)
{
    this->aimDir = sf::Vector2f(EnemyPos.x + 37 - this->tower_shot.getPosition().x, EnemyPos.y + 37 - this->tower_shot.getPosition().y);
    if (sqrt(pow(this->aimDir.x, 2) + pow(this->aimDir.y, 2)) < 250) return true;
    return false;
}

void Tower_shot::fire(sf::Vector2f EnemyPos, sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    this->aimDir = sf::Vector2f(EnemyPos.x + 37 - this->tower_shot.getPosition().x, EnemyPos.y + 37 - this->tower_shot.getPosition().y);
    this->aimDirNorm = sf::Vector2f(this->aimDir.x / sqrt(pow(this->aimDir.x, 2) + pow(this->aimDir.y, 2)), this->aimDir.y / sqrt(pow(this->aimDir.x, 2) + pow(this->aimDir.y, 2)));
    this->currVelocity = this->aimDirNorm * this->maxSpeed;
    animation.Update(row);
    tower_shot.setTextureRect(animation.uvRect);
    window.draw(tower_shot);
    this->tower_shot.move(this->currVelocity);
}
```

The problem is: bullets are act weird, like bullet can't decide to which enemy is moving and trying to move to every enemy in range. Any clues how to deal with that? I'm stuck

Comment: I would have a read of this ... https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I guess your "fire" method gets called to often. Please check with breakpoints (or 'cout's if you want to) how often it gets called. Also it is very bad practise to call the draw-function of the window in your update. Normally ALL(!) objects get updated and then everything gets drawn. Like this (just an example):   updateObjects(); window.clear(); drawObjects(); window.display().

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

https://github.com/dragneel30/Unnamed-TD-game/blob/master/Tower.h#L104

The tower is the one who should decide which enemy to fire, after that, it will create a bullet and pass the detected enemy to the bullet, then the bullet will store a pointer to that enemy, so given that, your bullet wont act weird anymore. because it already knows which enemy to follow (the stored enemy)